# Массив решетка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, arraylist

Нужна помощь в решении задачи

Заполните прямоугольный массив целыми числами по образцу (нули стоят на пересечении строк и
столбцов с нечетными номерами, в остальных клетках стоят единицы).

```
Пример для n=5m=6
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Все на что меня хватило

```
n, m = 5, 6
mtrx = [[((j+i)%2 + (i-1)%2) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
for k in mtrx:
    print(*k)
```

Output

```
1 2 1 2 1 2
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 2 1 2 1 2
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: Используйте логические и/или побитовые операции: `and`, `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n, m = 5, 6

mtrx = [ [ 0 if j % 2 and i % 2 else 1  for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
for k in mtrx:
    print(*k)
```

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо @extrn за обучение)

Вариант:

```
n, m = 5, 6
mtrx = [[(~j&1) | (~i)&1 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

for k in mtrx:
    print(*k)
```

Еще один:

```
n, m = 5, 6
mtrx= [[(1-j%2) | (i+1)%2 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

for k in mtrx:
    print(*k)
```

Comment: `~(i & j) & 1` :)

Comment: @extrn учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться)))